# AngularJS $anchorScroll adds ##-anchorname to page URL. How can I avoid this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS's locationhash() + $anchorScroll to move a selected page element to the top of the window once its contents have loaded in via Ajax.

JS: 
   In the controller:

```
     $scope.scrollTo = function (location) {
            //Scroll to category head
            $scope.categoryHead = "grouptitle-" + location;
            $location.hash($scope.categoryHead);
            $anchorScroll($scope.categoryHead);
     };
```

In the directive:

```
 .directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                var scroll;
                if (scope.$last === true) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        //Scroll category to top of page after list has completed render
                        scroll = scope.scrollTo(scope.category);
                    });
                }
            }
        };
```

This gives me a display URL of `mysite.com/##grouptitle-2` or similar, which looks a bit arcane. Is there any way to configure this anchor so that it either displays with only one hash, or doesn't modify the address bar URL at all?

Answer (score 0):

on your `$anchorScroll` remove the parameter. The anchorScroll will automatically grab the hash from `$location.hash(<hash>)`.

so your function should look something like this:

```
$scope.categoryHead = "grouptitle-" + location;
$location.hash($scope.categoryHead);
$anchorScroll();
```

If the DOM is updated dynamically then wrap the `$location.hash` and `$anchorScroll` inside `$timeout` function.

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps:
after this $location.hash($scope.categoryHead);
add

```js
$anchorScroll();
$location.hash('');
$location.replace();
```

$location.replace() function will remove '#' from url.

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps:
after this $location.hash($scope.categoryHead);
add

```
$anchorScroll();
$location.hash('');
$location.replace();
```

$location.replace() function will remove '#' from url.